# Authenticating application with spring security using neo4j database---Getting Exception

Tags: java, database, spring-security, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

please find below exception.

```
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/neo4j/Neo4jDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory]: Factory method 'sessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        ... 66 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory]: Factory method 'sessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        ... 75 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.neo4j.ogm.metadata.DomainInfo.registerDefaultMethodConverters(DomainInfo.java:379) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.1.3.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.metadata.DomainInfo.postProcessMethods(DomainInfo.java:215) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.1.3.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.metadata.DomainInfo.finish(DomainInfo.java:159) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.1.3.jar:na]
```

Anyone who can help me with neo4j and spring security.

Comment: which is NOT the JPA API, tag now removed!

Comment: Can you share the `DomainInfo` class ? It seems that you have a bad convertor in this

Comment: i found the issue. Forget to add @EntityScan("eu.bm.entities") below @SpringBootApplication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@EntityScan` annotation was missing due to which entities were not getting loaded.